# Inkscape colors wash out in conversion from .pdf to .eps

Tags: inkscape, color-conversion

I need to convert some academic graphics to .eps.  I don’t have the option of using a different final format.  In Inkscape most of the graphics files convert fine.  In one the colors selectively wash out within parts of the image.  Two side-by-side pairs of maps wash out in a distinct gradient that gets worse toward the upper right within each.  The colors in the legend between the pairs of maps are fine.  (The image is a .jpg of a screen capture of the .eps.)

If I export to .svg, the colors are bright throughout.  If I bring in the .svg and export that to .eps the same color degradation happens.  I have tried File, Clean up document without effect.  Ideas please?

[image: WashedOutResult]

Comment: I have no idea how inkscape do the conversion, may be using the pdf2ps command. Could you try the command `pdf2eps` ([details here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps)) to see the output?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is wrong with these images?  What are we supposed to be comparing them against? They look fine to me. Is this for a print job, or is it for a digital publication? How were the images constructed, are there any path effects, filters, or blending modes?  Not everything that will work in an SVG will work in an EPS.

Comment: What's wrong is the variable intensity of the colors in the maps.  In the top maps, the blue at the NE edge of the Amazon should be as bright as it is in the SW corner.  Also the map title should be bright black.  This is for digital publication.  I made the .pdf in r.  In the .pdf each of the map colors has uniform intensity across each map.  I opened the .pdf in Inkscape, then simply used File, Save As, chose EPS as the format, then Saved with all other defaults accepted.   I did no other manipulation in Inkscape.  Using .svg was just an attempt to see if the problem were format-specific.

Comment: Can you share both the pdf and eps files? If you zoom into the eps file: do white lines appear?

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be a similar problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418308/36296